# Manually copy sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a newcomer to the **Android** world. I have just completed a tutorial to work with sq-lite database. Now, I would like to get the database from my android device to my desktop.

I goggled this topic. But all of them are showing some code sample to do it. Is there any way to copy that database without code? I mean, copy the physical file to my PC.

Sorry if this question is ridiculous.

Thanks.

Comment: yes you can copy the database to you pc, but you have to install the application on emulator and then use DDMS perspective to fetch the Database.

Comment: when your device is rooted you can access it trough adb shell. it s in data/data/yourpackagename/databases.

Comment: @androidika, would you please explain litte more? How can i use adb shell? I am doing my first android app.

Comment: @SKPaul is your device rooted?

Comment: just connect your device via usb (or start an emulator) open your terminal and type "adb shell"  (adb should be in your path, its in the sdk bundle you downloaded form google). And bam! your on the root folder of your device. Note that the /data folder is only accesseble on rooted devices (emulator should work also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the DDMS perspective, select your emulator.
2. Then goto /data/data/your.app.name/databases/
3. Select your db
4. Click on the icon with a floppy disk
5. Select a path on your PC

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps to pull database to your desktop

```
On command prompt type:
adb pull /data/data/yourpackagename/databases/databasename.db

your package name will be like com.example.androidapp

It will pull database file in current directory. now try

sqlite3 databasename.db on command prompt

use sqlite commands to view tables, like select * from tablename etc;
```

to use adb , add path to /platform tools.